# Adaptation of Milnor's Homotopy Lemma

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

In Chapter 5 of Milnor's Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint there is the following theorem:

**Theorem B:** If $f$ is smootly homotopic to $g$, then $\operatorname{deg}f = \operatorname{deg}g$.

It is stated that the proof of this result to be similar to Homotopy Lemma's proof, which appears in this same book. However, I do not see how to adapt one proof to the other, since I do not know how to go from the degree modulo 2 to the general case.

Can someone point out how do I make such an adaptation?

Comment: As the mod 2 proof indicates, you first assume that $y$ is a regular value of $f$, $g$ and their homotopy $F$. The preimage is a 1-dimensional submanifold whose connected components connect the points in the corrsponding preimages of $f$ and $g$. Now, you need to think of what happens to the orientation when you transport the differentials along these paths.